# Using iron-router with angular-meteor makes controllers being loaded twice

Tags: iron-router, angular-meteor

I have a Meteor application using angular-meteor. I need now to load different angular modules depending on url. I added iron-router to my application to do so and I continue to handle routes for each module using ngRoute and anchor nav but it behaves strangely if url contains params. I made a small test case which is available here:

https://github.com/clouchtibat/iron-router-ng-route

If you click on 'truc' link and then on 'test', next routes changes will make controller be instantiated two times. It works if urls have no params.

I also tested with ui-router (in the with-ui-router branch) and the problem is the same but in addition view is duplicated.

Is this a bug in one of the two routers or is there something wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this conversations in the angular-meteor Github issues:

https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/154

[https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/493](https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/154)

I think it can help you with some directions.
I am also having some hard time with mixin angular-meteor and iron:router.

Comment: I think the problem here is different, I have been trying to apply this fix (https://github.com/gmr2/GimmeRide/blob/master/client/ng/routes.js) to clouchtibat's repository for the past three hours but the main issue he faces is because he still uses ngRoute as a "main" router. Do you have any idea about how we could fit your fix to that ?